# How can I take user input separated by space in Java

Tags: java, user-input

```
System.out.print("Enter an integer width and height between 2 and 25: ");
String[] str = sc.next().split(" ");
System.out.print(str.length);
```

I want to take user input separated by space but it is only taking first input.

[image]

Comment: Try "scanner.next()" without the split.  You should get "10", then "20".  If you saved to a List<String> instead of a String[] array, then you should be able to read your tokens directly from user input into your Java container.

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: Include the definition of `sc` - it is assumed that it is a `Scanner` but how it is defined impacts how it behaves.

Answer (score 0):

You should use *sc.nextLine()* insteand of *sc.next()*.

As per javadoc, *sc.next()*
`Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.`

*sc.next()* will return first "**token**" (10 in your case, as your input is tokenized by "space" between 10 and 20).

So your code should look like below, for what you expect:

```java
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter an integer width and height between 2 and 25: ");
    String[] str = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
    System.out.print(str.length);
    sc.close();
```

Comment: No it's not working. It is not taking input @Shashwat

Comment: How did you initialize your Scanner?
There is nothing that shouldn't work. It's fairly simple piece of code.